# How to hide filter buttons in Einstein (wave) Analytics dashboards?

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein

**Description:**

Einstein Analytics dashboards integrated into Lightning Pages with filters, come with 'Modified' and '+X filters' buttons on top (see image below).

[image]

**Question:**

Is there any way to remove or disable them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uncheck Show Header on the Lightning Page, Wave Dashboard component.  This removes the header bar which has the Filters component.

If your filter is set at the dashboard, rather than added on the Lightning Page, you can also Lock a global filter at design time.  Locked can be set either through the Dashboard Designer if using the Filter panel or directly in the JSON.

Comment: indeed, unchecking the 'show title' and 'show header' options _together_ worked!  thanks Carl!

Answer (score 0):

its all because of the saved views coming into the play, so create a two permission sets one having this permission under settings "Enable Wave dashboard saved views" other not having this feature. assign the permission set which doesnt have "Enable Wave dashboard saved views" to the user so that he will not be able to edit the pre defined filters.

else you can just uncheck the "Enable Wave dashboard saved views" in the analytics-->settings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but Carl's solution already fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Dashboard-->select edit on the right side options--> select filter and delete it

Please mark it as answer if it works.

Comment: I want to keep the filter but don't want the user to see that there is a filter applied on the lens. Thanks but your answer doesn't provide the solution that I am looking for.